# Не могу записать данные в переменную (async, await)

Tags: node.js

Не могу получить данные из ДБ.

```
const {Router} = require('express');
const router = Router();
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const path = require('path');
const dbPath = path.join('data', 'data.db');

router.post('/data', async (req, res) => {
  const db = new sqlite.Database(dbPath);
  const { page } = req.headers;
  const firstItemOnPage = page * 50 - 50;

  let data = []

  db.all(`SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ${firstItemOnPage}, 50`, [], (err, row) => {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }
    data = row;
    // Ожидаю, что данные будут записаны в переменную, но запрос к ДБ ещё не обработан и код пошёл дальше.
    // Как быть? Может Генераторы?
  })

  res.json(data);
  db.close();
})

module.exports = router;
```

На front приходит только []. Я примерно понимаю, что это связано с асинхронностью, но как это поправить я не нашёл, мучаюсь 5-й день. Не судите строго, я новенький XD.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто вставить отправку ответа с сервера внутрь запроса в базу и тогда нормально отрабатывать будет или обернуть запрос в базу в промис и авейтом ждать пока отработает функция и уже чтото делать с результатом.

```js
router.post('/data', async (req, res) => {
  const db = new sqlite.Database(dbPath);
  const { page } = req.headers;
  const firstItemOnPage = page * 50 - 50;

  let data = []

  db.all(`SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ${firstItemOnPage}, 50`, [], (err, row) => {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }
    data = row;
    res.json(data);
  })
  db.close();
})

//Или 
router.post('/data', async (req, res) => {
  const db = new sqlite.Database(dbPath);
  const { page } = req.headers;
  const firstItemOnPage = page * 50 - 50;

  let data = [];
  
  let result = await example(db, firstItemOnPage);
  
  data.push(result);
  
  res.json(data);
  db.close();
})

example = (db, firstItemOnPage) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.all(`SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ${firstItemOnPage}, 50`, [], (err, row) => {
            if (error) {
                reject('Error');
            } else {
                resolve(row);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант, я пробовал, есть проблема, нужно 2 запроса к БД к 2-м разным таблицам, а вот второй вариант, спасибо, мне очень нравится. Я конечно немного (много) наглею, но можно ли в example вернуть 2 промиса? Я очень новичок.

Comment: Смотря что тебе нужно, если исходя из того что ты вытащил зделать еще 1 запрос можешь построить цепочку промисов и через then вызвать 2 функцию которая будет делать другой запрос или опять же просто создай еще 1 example только с другим запросом который тебе нужен и так же с ним работай.